# Stop task when there is an exception thrown in ItemProcessor

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I am designing a Spring Batch, which reads multiple csv files. I have used partitioning to read each file in chunk and process it to decrypt a certain column in the csv. Before decrypting if i encounter any validation error , i throw custom exception.

Now what i want is if the processing finds any validation error in the first line, the other lines should not be processed, and the job should end.
How can i achieve this? I tried to implement ProcessorListener too but it has no StepExecution object so that i can call SetTerminateOnly() or ExitStatus=Failed

Also note that i have multiple thread accessing the file in different lines.I want to kill all threads in the event of the first encountered error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I identified that running multiple asynchronous concurrent threads (Spring Batch partitioning) was the real issue. Though one of the thread threw an Exception, the other threads were parallely running, and finished executing till the end.
Ath the end, the Job FAILED overall and there was no output processed, but it consumed time to process rest of the data.

Well,the solution to it is as simple as it gets. We just need stop the Job while encountering an error during processing.

**The Custom Processor**

```
  public class MultiThreadedFlatFileItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<BinFileVO, BinFileVO>,JobExecutionListener{
    private JobExecution jobExecution;
    private RSADecrypter decrypter;
    
    public RSADecrypter getDecrypter() {
        return decrypter;
    }
    
    public void setDecrypter(RSADecrypter decrypter) { 
        this.decrypter = decrypter;
    }
    @Override
    /**
     This method is used process the encrypted data
     @param item
     * */
    public BinFileVO process(BinFileVO item) throws JobException {
        if(null!=item.getEncryptedText() && !item.getEncryptedText().isEmpty()){
            String decrypted = decrypter.getDecryptedText(item.getEncryptedText());
            if(null!=decrypted && !decrypted.isEmpty()){
                 if(decrypted.matches("[0-9]+")){
                     if(decrypted.length() >= 12 && decrypted.length() <= 19){
                         item.setEncryptedText(decrypted);
                     }else{
                         this.jobExecution.stop();
                         throw new JobException(PropertyLoader.getValue(ApplicationConstants.DECRYPTED_CARD_NO_LENGTH_INVALID),item.getLineNumber());
                     }
                 }
         }else{
             this.jobExecution.stop();
             throw new JobException(PropertyLoader.getValue(ApplicationConstants.EMPTY_ENCRYPTED_DATA),item.getLineNumber());
         }
         return item;
     }
    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            this.jobExecution=jobExecution;
    }
    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        
    }
  }
```

**The Job xml config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   .....>
  <!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
  <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />
  <bean id="jobLauncher"    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
     <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
  </bean>       

 <!-- Job Details -->
    <job id="simpleMultiThreadsReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="step" >
            <partition step="step1" partitioner="partitioner">
                <handler grid-size="5" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
            </partition>
        </step>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="decryptingItemProcessor"/>
        </listeners>
    </job>
  
    <step id="step1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" processor="decryptingItemProcessor" commit-interval="500"/>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="customItemProcessorListener" />
            </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <!-- Processor Details -->
    <bean id="decryptingItemProcessor" class="com.test.batch.io.MultiThreadedFlatFileItemProcessor">
        <property name="decrypter" ref="rsaDecrypter" />
    </bean>     
    <!-- RSA Decrypter class -->    
    <bean id="rsaDecrypter" class="test.batch.secure.rsa.client.RSADecrypter"/>
    
    <!-- Partitioner Details -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />
    <bean id="partitioner" class="com.test.batch.partition.FlatFilePartitioner" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" ref="inputFile"/>
    </bean>
     <bean id="taskExecutor"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="10"/>
    </bean>
   <!-- Step will need a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
    ........
    .................
</beans>
```

**Here are the logs**

> 2016-09-01 06:32:40 INFO  SimpleJobRepository:273 - Parent JobExecution is stopped, so passing message on to StepExecution
>
> 2016-09-01 06:32:43 INFO  ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy:60 - Step interrupted through StepExecution
>
> 2016-09-01 06:32:43 INFO  AbstractStep:216 - Encountered interruption executing step: Job interrupted status detected.
>
> ; org.springframework.batch.core.JobInterruptedException
> 2016-09-01 06:32:45 ERROR CustomJobListener:163 - exception :At line No. 1 : The decrypted card number is less than 12 or greater than 19 in length
>
> 2016-09-01 06:32:45 ERROR CustomJobListener:163 - exception :Job interrupted status detected.
>
> 2016-09-01 06:32:45 INFO  SimpleJobLauncher:135 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=simpleMultiThreadsReaderJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{outputFile=/usr/local/pos/bulktokenization/csv/outputs/cc_output_EDWError_08162016.csv, partitionFile=/usr/local/pos/bulktokenization/csv/partitions/, inputFile=C:\usr\local\pos\bulktokenization\csv\inputs\cc_input_EDWError_08162016.csv, fileName=cc_input_EDWError_08162016}] and the following status: [FAILED]
>
> 2016-09-01 06:32:45 INFO  BatchLauncher:122 - Exit Status : FAILED
>
> 2016-09-01 06:32:45 INFO  BatchLauncher:123 - Time Taken : 8969

Answer (score 1):

If we throw Custom Exception in Processor, Spring Batch will terminate and mark the job failed unless you setup 'skipable' exception. You have not mentioned where you perform validate step, are you doing in Processor or Reader? Let me know because it is where Spring Batch decides.

In my project, if I want to stop the job and throw Custom Exception, we put validation logic in a Tasklet or Processor and throw exception as below

```
private AccountInfoEntity getAccountInfo(Long partnerId) {
        if(partnerId != null){
            .....
            return ....;
        } else {
            throw new ReportsException("XXXXX");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am doing in Processor..i use BinFileVO process(BinFileVO item) throws Exception{ If(item.getEncryptedText().length > 10) throw new Exception("Invalid input length"); return item }.    This does not stop the job to process the rest of the file. It only shows the exception at last in afterJob in JobListener as JobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions and shows Job Status = FAILED

Comment: I am implementing ItemProcessor interface and throwing the exception from it. But it will always return the item.. i tried using ItemProcessorListener too and use the method afterProcess and onProcessError. But it has no stepexecution object to stop the batch explicitly

Comment: Are you sure you don't setup 'retry-policy' or 'skippable-exception-classes'?

If you want to have StepExecution object in Processor, you can achieve it as below

1. Implement StepExecutionListener for your Processor
2. Declare a StepExecution variable in your Processor
3. In BeforeStep method, save stepExecution object
4. In Process method, you can use it.

Comment: No i am not declaring any retry-policy or skippable exception. Do i have to inject stepexecution in my processor bean and stepexecutionlistener bean? And will it be shared between the two? I will try it and share the code here

Comment: You can try as below
public class XXX implements ItemProcessor<X>, StepExecutionListener {
 private StepExecution stepExecution;
 
 public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    public X process(X item) throws Exception { 
  // you can start using this.stepExecution
 } 
}

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try it and update your answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Please look at my answer i have posted above. I need a different question now as to how to terminate all threads if one fails in spring batch partitioning. I know that Spring partitioning uses asynchronous threads, and that is creating a huge problem for me.

Comment: I think you can research a bit about SimpleJobOperator. That is one option I can think of right now. You can have a bean for that one and inject it to your Processor. And if there is any exception happens in your processor, you can stop the job by using 'stop' method of SimpleJobOperator. The method requires 'jobId', you can have it by implement JobExeuctionListener from your Processor.

Comment: I tried using .stop() method too. But the slave steps(threads) keep executing. The job does not exits at this point. :(

Comment: I have just written an small program to check if jobOperator works as we thought. I do see it is working. Please refer to the link https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/stop-spring-batch-job-if-a-thread-of-the-processor-caught-an-exception/

Comment: You are using `JobOperator` , but here i am using `JobLauncher` to run my job, and return the `ExecutionContext`. Should i set `Job` in JobOperator and start my job execution by calling the start method? Your above code is still not working for me.

Comment: I'm also using JobLauncher to launch the job. Please see the code I updated from the above link. I just use JobOperator to stop the job in Processor.

Comment: I updated my answer. I was able to achieve it by implementing JobExecution listener in processor and declaring my processor as "job listener" as well as "item processor" in the Job. :)